# hasOwnProperty always returns false on object with variable properties

Tags: typescript, dictionary, properties

I'm consuming some k8s objects with typescript and my json looks like this:

```
{
 "startTime": "2022-12-01T19:15:58Z",
  "taskRuns": {
     "task1": {
        "pipelineTaskName": "task1Ref",
         "status": {
             "completionTime": "2022-12-01T19:17:27Z",
              "conditions": [
                 {
                   "lastTransitionTime": "2022-12-01T19:17:27Z",
                   "message": "",
                   "reason": "TaskRunImagePullFailed",
                   "status": "False",
                   "type": "Succeeded"
                  }
               ]}},
   "task2":{same fields as task1},
   "task3": {same}
}}
```

I also have an array with the TaskRun names which looks like the following:

```
["task1","task2",....]
```

The relevant interface for the object above looks like:

```
export interface PipelineRunStatus {
  startTime: string;
  taskRuns: Truns;
}
export interface Truns {
  [key: string]: TaskRun;
}
export interface TaskRUn {<fields from above>}
```

I'm trying to match the array elements to the variable task keys in a taskrun and extract information with the code below:

```
    type taskRunKey = keyof typeof currentRun.Status.taskRuns
    //taskRuns is my string array
     taskRuns.map((taskRunName: string) => {
     console.log(taskRunName)

     if (currentRun?.Status?.taskRuns?.hasOwnProperty(taskRunName as taskRunKey))
          console.log(currentRun.Status?.taskRuns[taskRunName as status?.conditions[0])
      else {
          console.log(currentRun?.Status?.taskRuns)
          console.log(currentRun?.Status)
       }
```

but this prints

```
task1
undefined
Object { TaskRuns: {… task1:{..the object above...}}}
​
task2
undefined
Object { TaskRuns: {… pretty much the object above...}}
​
```

etc

In short: the code above always ends up in the "else" branch of the statement despite the fact that there is an object property with the correct name that matches.
Can someone please explain what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a few things wrong:

1. Typo in "taskRuns" it should be "TaskRuns" and typescript for some reason doesn't deserialise JSON case insensitive (like golang does). I changed my types to be
   `export interface PipelineRunStatus { startTime: string; TaskRuns: Truns; }`
2. `hasOwnProperty` is incorrect, I needed instead : `Object.keys(currentRun?.Status?.TaskRuns).includes(taskRunName)`

Thank you everyone who spent time on this!